# Predicting which population generated my observation

Tags: regression, classification, prediction

I am trying to predict which of my two populations generated an observation.

I have two samples from my two populations, and for future observations, I want to decide which population they belong to.

What is the best way to approach this?

[image: The distributions of two samples]

Comment: Look into logistic regression, search this site.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen isn't logistic regression for estimating a dependent variable given a set of independent variables? I want to estimate the class of a variable based on it's value alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of this as a [binary classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_classification) problem; there are a number of different algorithms you can use. @kjetilbhalvorsen points out a commonly used one, logistic regression. Logistic regression need not be used purely for parameter estimation, as you seem to think; any fitted model can be used for prediction. In this case, a fitted logistic regression model can be used to predict the probability of belonging to either class/population.

Aside from logistic regression, you could use decision trees, random forests, support vector machines, or neural networks, among others.